# nortel VPN client for window 7 , processor type not supported error

Tags: vpn

I am trying to install Nortel VPN Client V 10.04.016 on my machine.

Machine configuration:
Intel Core i5 processor 64 bit.
Windows 7 Home basic

While running setup its give me an error saying
"The Installer package (NVC32) is not supported by this processor type."

Please help me how to install the same?

Answer (score 0):

If the below dialog is similar (Win 7 styling) to what you describe, then this coupled with the fact the error included NVC **32** in it, I would guess that you were using the 32bit version of the VPN client, on your 64bit Machine+Windows version.

[image]

I found [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20110209184808/http://blog.michaelfmcnamara.com/2010/03/nortel-vpn-client-release-10-04-016-for-windows-7/#comment-3187) link that demonstrates (Despite the contradictory wording of the introductory paragraph) that there was two separate installers for each bitage.